# How to render a view/partial in a helper w/o the layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello in a helper I'm doing the following:

```
render(:template =>"feeds/_feed_item.html.erb", :locals => { :feed_item => feed_item }).to_s
```

Problem is this is rendering the layout which I don't want. How can I render just the file/template feed_item ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the option `:layout => false` to render without the layout.

Example:

```
render(:template =>"feeds/_feed_item.html.erb", :layout => nil , :locals => { :feed_item => feed_item }).to_s
```

Comment: Can you render this in a model somehow?

Comment: Try using  a partial for this. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: It must be `layout => nil`, at least in Rails 3.1! Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the :partial key, the template shouldn't be rendered.  Try this:

```
render :partial => 'feeds/feed_item', :locals => { :feed_item => feed_item }).to_s
```

Depending on your setup, you may also be able to shorten this to simply:

```
render feed_item
```

Comment: Can you render this in a model somehow?

Comment: I've never done it, but this looks promising.  http://tumblr.seebq.com/post/39566909/rails-code-render-a-view-from-a-model-require

Comment: There's a trailing parenthesis in this answer, can you remove it?