# Rails helper use

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, helper

I'm writing a simple page that will help me view the sync status of my sites custom gallery compared to my Flickr account.

I have a simple loop that iterates over a response from the Flickr API:

```
<% for collection in @flickr_hierarchy %>
  <%= traverse_collection(collection, 0) %>
<% end %>
```

`traverse_collection` is a Rails helper method as so:

```
module GalleryHelper

  def traverse_collection(collection, parent)
    parent = parent == 0 ? 0 : parent["id"]

    content_tag(:tr) do
      content_tag(:td, 'Collection')

      collectionLocal = Collection.where(flickr_id: collection.id).first

      if collectionLocal != nil
        content_tag(:td, 'Yes')
      else
        content_tag(:td, 'No')
      end
      content_tag(:td, '&nbsp;')
      content_tag(:td, '&nbsp;')
      content_tag(:td, collection.title)
      content_tag(:td, collection.id)
      content_tag(:td, parent.to_s)
      content_tag(:td, 'N/A')
      content_tag(:td) do
        if collectionLocal != nil
          button_to('Add all Sets', admin_add_all_sets_for_collection_path(flickr_collection_id: collection.id))
          button_to('Delete Collection', admin_delete_collection_path(flickr_collection_id: collection.id))
        else
          button_to('Add Collection', admin_add_collection_path(flickr_collection_id: collection.id, flickr_parent_collection_id: parent.to_s))
          button_to('Add Collection and Sets', admin_add_all_sets_for_collection_path(flickr_collection_id: collection.id, flickr_parent_collection_id: parent.to_s))
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Unfortunately i've found out that there is no nice or non-messy code way to get the generated HTML to be output on my page.

Is there a good way to do this or should I be taking a different approach. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Neil

Comment: Could you explain the problem? Are you trying to take the HTML logic out of the helper?

Comment: @kendotwill I can't get the generated HTML to be output when I run that helper method from my view.

Comment: Are you trying to generate the HTML after the page has already been loaded?

Comment: Can you provide more code, the controller?

Comment: @kendotwill  No code is being generated after the page has loaded. There's no need for me to post the controller code. I have an var called `@flickr_hierarchy`. For each item of it I want to run that helper method which should spit out a chunk of HTML for the page to display. The display does not happen. I am assuming the HTML is being generated but I don;t know how to get it to output onto my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the assembly of the HTML out of your helper and into a partial. Create a file `app/views/gallery/_row.html.erb` (you can name it whatever you want, but make sure the file starts with an underscore) and put your HTML there, like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>Collection</td>
  <td><%= collection_local.present? ? "Yes" : "No" %></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><%= collection.title %></td>
  <td><%= collection.id %></td>
  <td><%= parent %></td>
  <td>N/A</td>
  <td>
    <% if collection_local.present? %>
      <%= button_to(
            "Add all Sets", 
            admin_add_all_sets_for_collection_path(flickr_collection_id: collection.id)
            ) %>
      <%= button_to(
            "Delete Collection",
            admin_delete_collection_path(flickr_collection_id: collection.id)
            ) %>
    <% else %>
      <%= button_to(
            "Add Collection", 
            admin_add_collection_path(
              flickr_collection_id: collection.id, 
              flickr_parent_collection_id: parent.to_s
            )) %>
      <%= button_to(
            "Add Collection and Sets",
            admin_add_all_sets_for_collection_path(
              flickr_collection_id: collection.id, 
              flickr_parent_collection_id: parent.to_s
            )) %>
    <% end %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Now all your helper has to do is call `render` with the name of the partial and the "locals" (variables) that your partial needs. The name in this case is `gallery/row` (filename without the underscore and extension), and the variables that the partial needs are: `collection`, `collection_local`, and `parent`. Therefore the render call would look like this:

```
module GalleryHelper

  def traverse_collection(collection, parent)
    parent = parent == 0 ? 0 : parent["id"]
    collection_local = Collection.where(flickr_id: collection.id).first

    render(
      partial: "gallery/row",
      locals: {
        collection: collection,
        collection_local: collection_local,
        parent: parent
      })
  end
end
```

Does that help?

There is more information about how to use partials in the official [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I shall give that a go hopefully this evening when I get time. Thanks. I shall report back with how I get on.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for helping me see where I should have separated the concerns and keeping my code more agile and tidy!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `render` in your helper method.

Please see [How to render a view/partial in a helper w/o the layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319321/how-to-render-a-view-partial-in-a-helper-w-o-the-layout)

Just wrap the template with your business/presentation logic in a helper method, prepare your scope and let the rendering engine do the rendering.

Does that help?

**UPDATE**

You can call practically everything in your helper method including `render`, which will instruct Rails engine to render any view/partial into request response

This is the helper implementation

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def hello()
    # Prepare your model into locals, which will be passed to your partial
    # template
    render partial: 'shared/hello', locals: {text: 'world'}
  end
end
```

This is the partial template used in helper method

```
<!-- views/shared/_hello.html.erb -->
<div>hello <%= text %></div>
```

This is the main controller view orchestrating the request

```
<!-- views/welcome/index.html.erb -->
<h1>Test</h1>
<%= hello %>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but i'm confused as how to use this to get it to work?  Could you expand further in the context of my original question?

Comment: Please see my update. This should clarify your problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a plus sign `+` at the end of each `content_tag` and maybe the `button_to`. Otherwise only the last content_tag will get created.

```
module GalleryHelper

  def traverse_collection(collection, parent)
    parent = parent == 0 ? 0 : parent["id"]

    collectionLocal = Collection.where(flickr_id: collection.id).first

    content_tag(:tr) do
      content_tag(:td, 'Collection') +

      content_tag(:td, (collectionLocal != nil) ? 'Yes' : 'No' ) +
      content_tag(:td, '&nbsp;') + 
      content_tag(:td, '&nbsp;') +
      content_tag(:td, collection.title) +
      content_tag(:td, collection.id) +
      content_tag(:td, parent.to_s) +
      content_tag(:td, 'N/A') +
      content_tag(:td) do
        if collectionLocal != nil
          button_to('Add all Sets', admin_add_all_sets_for_collection_path(flickr_collection_id: collection.id)) +
          button_to('Delete Collection', admin_delete_collection_path(flickr_collection_id: collection.id))
        else
          button_to('Add Collection', admin_add_collection_path(flickr_collection_id: collection.id, flickr_parent_collection_id: parent.to_s)) +
          button_to('Add Collection and Sets', admin_add_all_sets_for_collection_path(flickr_collection_id: collection.id, flickr_parent_collection_id: parent.to_s))
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

[Rails- nested content_tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205613/rails-nested-content-tag)

Comment: This makes no difference what so ever.

Comment: @rctneil I tested it with the assumption that `@flickr_hierarchy` is not nil. If you view the source in the browser after after loading the page and you don't see an empty tr `<tr></tr>` then you function is not being called at all. I would start by debugging if your `for` is being executed. You will need a `+` at the end of your `content_tags` if you want to fix your current code.